# How do I fix request timeout when trying to sing up a user in cognito via .net

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Does somebody know how to fix request timeout by gateway (504) when trying to register a user into cognito? I use it with AWS Api gateway. locally it runs with no problem, but when I upload it into AWS lambda it gets a request timeout.

When I have te code below with the await it timesout. When I leave the await away it will not timeout but it also will not register the user in cognito.

```
  private static readonly string _clientId = DotNetEnv.Env.GetString("AWS_CLIENT_ID", null);
    private static readonly string _poolId = DotNetEnv.Env.GetString("AWS_USER_POOL", null);

    private static AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient CreateCognitoClient()
    {
        return new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());
    }

    /*
    * Method name: regsiterAsync
    * @param1: user (User), contains the basic userdata for registering a user (email, username, password, name)
    * returns: Response (object)
    **/
    public static async Task<Response> registerAsync(User user)
    {
        Response response = new Response();
        /*
        * Check if user already exists in our database.
        **/
        if (DbHandler.getUserByEmail(user.email) == null)
        {
            /*
            * Create a signup request to be sent to amazon cognito. 
            **/
            SignUpRequest signUpRequest = new SignUpRequest()
            {
                ClientId = _clientId,
                Username = user.email,
                Password = user.password,
                UserAttributes = new List<Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.AttributeType>
                {
                    new AttributeType
                    {
                        Name = "email",
                        Value = user.email
                    }
                }
            };

            try
            {
                /*
                * Send singup request to amazon cognito
                * Returns a SingUpRequest(object)
                **/
                using(var cognitoClient = CreateCognitoClient())
                {
                    var signUpResult = await cognitoClient.SignUpAsync(signUpRequest);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                /*
                * Incase that a error accoured by sending the SingUpRequest to cognito. Return a error response.
                **/
                response.status = "failed";
                response.message = e.Message;
                return response;
            }

            /*
            * Add user to our database
            **/
            User storedUser = DbHandler.addUser(user);

            /*
            * Return response with success data 
            **/
            response.message = "User successful registered.";
            response.data = storedUser;

            return response;
        }
        /*
        * In case the user already exists in our database. Return a non successful response 
        **/
        response.status = "failed";
        response.message = "User already exists.";

        return response;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the `timeout` value of the lambda function under `Basic settings` section. Default value for timeout is 3 seconds and your function takes more than that.